# Split Hashes into arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a Hash table which holds key and values as array. I need to split it into different array with valid values.

```
hash = {:fruits => [:apple, :banana, :mango] , :veggies => [:capsicum, :onion]}
```

I want to create an array like this:

```
array = [
  {:fruits => :apple, :veggies => :capsicum},
  {:fruits => :apple, :veggies => :onion}
  # ...
]
```

Should contain all valid conditions.

Comment: You `array` isn't valid Ruby syntax. Do you mean something like: `array = [[{ :fruits => :apple }, { :veggies => :capsicum }] ...` or `array = [{ :fruits => :apple, :veggies => :capsicum } ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keys = hash.keys
first, *rest = hash.values
first.product(*rest).map{|values| keys.zip(values).to_h} # =>
# [
#   {:fruits=>:apple, :veggies=>:capsicum},
#   {:fruits=>:apple, :veggies=>:onion},
#   {:fruits=>:banana, :veggies=>:capsicum},
#   {:fruits=>:banana, :veggies=>:onion},
#   {:fruits=>:mango, :veggies=>:capsicum},
#   {:fruits=>:mango, :veggies=>:onion}
# ]
```

Comment: For static keys, this can be written as: `hash[:fruits].product(hash[:veggies]).map { |f, v| { fruit: f, veggie: v } }` (the singular form is intended)